# special character like ' not showing properly in pdf

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdf

I using html2fpdf library to generate a pdf in codeigniter .I have some data in a varchar field like "**What are your child’s academic strengths?**"  which is showing like " **What are your childâ€™s academic strengths?**" .

How I can show it as it is in the database .(I have tried htmlspecialchars_decode , html_entity_decode function but it not worked. )

Comment: did you try utf8_encode?

Comment: Please note that the ' in "child’s" is not a single quote ' char. Would it be a solution to replace it with a single quote?

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe in retrieval,insertion of data from/to mysql using php
You need to set the charset before saving stuff to db or reading them back.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

See [UTF8, PHP and MySQL](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: After i change the character set it showing properly as html but when i am converting that html to pdf the problem is still remain as same.